# angular 2 handle click on link inside iframe

Tags: html, angular, typescript, iframe

Is there a way to catch a click on a link inside an `iframe`?

```
<iframe *ngIf="currentFrameUrl" id="contentFrame" [src]="currentFrameUrl | safe"></iframe>
```

My iframe component contains just a simple code which subscribes to observable variables.

```
export class ContentFrameComponent implements OnInit {
    currentFrameUrl: string;
    currentMenuState: boolean;
    @ViewChild('contentFrame') iframe: ElementRef;

    constructor(private frameService: ContentFrameService) {        
      this.currentMenuState = true;      
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.frameService.providerCurrentUrl$.subscribe(data => this.currentFrameUrl = data);
      this.frameService.providerMenuState$.subscribe(data => this.currentMenuState = data);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      let doc = this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument ||this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow;
      if (typeof doc.addEventListener !== undefined) {
        console.log("inside if - addEventListener") // Is shown
        doc.addEventListener("click", this.iframeClickHandler, false)
      } else if (typeof doc.attachEvent !== undefined) {
        console.log("inside if - attachEvent ") // Does not show
        doc.attachEvent("onclick", this.iframeClickHandler)
      }
    }

    iframeClickHandler(): void {
      console.log("Click test") // Does not show
    }
}
```

My goal is to to catch click event on `iframe` link, stop its propagation and set the url of the iframe link using either `router.navigate` or `location.go`/`location.replaceState`. Not sure yet which option is better.

I have no control over the pages loaded inside the `iframe`. I only know, that the links should contains such `url` that can be used with my dynamic routes.

Comment: is the iframe served from the same domain as the host page?

Comment: yes, I'm working on a overlay to an intranet application.

Answer (score 5):

use @HostListener('window:blur', ['$event']) decorator, method attached with this decorator trigger on IFrame click.

```
  @HostListener('window:blur', ['$event'])
  onWindowBlur(event: any): void {
    console.log('iframe clicked');
  }
```

Note: Also this will work for cross-domain operations.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe *ngIf="currentFrameUrl" id="contentFrame" [src]="currentFrameUrl | safe" #iframe></iframe>
```

And

```
export class ContentFrameComponent implements OnInit {
      currentFrameUrl: string;
      currentMenuState: boolean;
      @ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;

      constructor(private frameService: ContentFrameService) {
        this.currentMenuState = true;
      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.frameService.providerCurrentUrl$.subscribe(data => this.currentFrameUrl = data);
        this.frameService.providerMenuState$.subscribe(data => this.currentMenuState = data);
      }

      ngAfterViewInit() {
        let doc = this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument || this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow;
        if (typeof doc.addEventListener !== undefined) {
          doc.addEventListener("click", this.iframeClickHandler, false)
        } else if (typeof doc.attachEvent !== undefined) {
          doc.attachEvent("onclick", this.iframeClickHandler);
        }
      }

      iframeClickHandler() {
        alert("Iframe clicked");
      }
    }
```

Note: this might not work for cross-domain operations.

Comment: it compiles, shows no errors but when I add `console.log()` inside `addEventListener` if, it show but then the `iframeClickHandler` does not show anything.

Comment: Tested, the code is working as expected at my end. Are we missing something?

Comment: Mind the `#contentFrame` .The iframe tag should go as `<iframe *ngIf="currentFrameUrl" #contentFrame [src]="currentFrameUrl | safe"></iframe>`

Comment: so I was able to see a "Click test" log while furiously clicking on `iframe` while loading. After it was fully loaded I was no more able to see the log.

Comment: Could you try this? `<iframe *ngIf="currentFrameUrl" #contentFrame (load)="onIframeLoad()" [src]="currentFrameUrl | safe"></iframe>`

And place the contents of `ngAfterViewInit` in `onIframeLoad`

Comment: Error: Permission denied to access property "addEventListener"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145461/discussion-between-jokingbatman-and-dallows).

Answer (score -2):

Why you can not use simple onclick?

Try this code:

```
<iframe *ngIf="currentFrameUrl" id="contentFrame" [src]="currentFrameUrl | safe" (onclick)="clicked()"></iframe>
```

clicked

Comment: I tried that but it looks like nothing is happening. I have `console.log` call inside the clicked function and it does not show.

Comment: Try to use directive with @Hostlistener.